# How is the Laplacian in spherical derived?

Tags: spherical-coordinates, laplacian

Suppose $\Phi$ is a function of $r, \theta$ and $\phi$. If I want to derive the Laplacian for this function, I would assume that..

$$\nabla ^2 \Phi = \nabla \cdot \nabla \Phi$$

And as, in spherical:

$$\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \hat r + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \hat \theta + \frac{1}{r  \sin \ \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat \phi$$

Which implies

$$\nabla \Phi= \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r} \hat r + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta} \hat \theta + \frac{1}{r  \sin \ \theta} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \phi} \hat \phi$$

Thus, the Laplacian would seem to me to be:

$$\large\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \\ 
 \frac{1}{r  \sin \ \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r} \\
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta} \\ 
 \frac{1}{r  \sin \ \theta} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \phi} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which will *not* give me the form for the Laplacian in spherical coordinates in my lecture notes or the internet. Where do I have it wrong?

Comment: This is a point in which the notation $\nabla\cdot$ for the divergence is slightly misleading. Don't interpret it as a true scalar product, it is not, just a mnemonic.

Comment: Well... that is indeed misleading. What am I supposed to do instead?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOT719oYmt0 The issue is that when you take the derivatives of  $\hat r, \hat\theta, \hat \phi$, as opposed to the Cartesian case, those are not zero

Answer (score 4):

The Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient. And the divergence in spherical coordinates is:
$$\nabla\cdot \mathbf A = {1 \over r^2}{\partial \left( r^2 A_r \right) \over \partial r}
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta} \left(  A_\theta\sin\theta \right)
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial A_\varphi \over \partial \varphi}$$

Now substitute the $\nabla\Phi$ that you already have for $\mathbf A$.

That leaves the question how we got that formula for the divergence. You can find the derivation here: [Nabla in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). It explains it in terms of how divergence is defined.